# Unable to get value of the property 'click': object is null or undefined

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, onclick

So I want a Button1 to be clicked when the submit button has been clicked.

Here is the relevant code:

```
<input id="Submit1" type="submit" value="Search" onclick="javascript:check_user()" /> 
<script type="text/javascript">
            function check_user() {
                document.getElementById('<%=Button1.ClientID%>').click();
            }  
</script>
<asp:Button id="Button1" runat="server" Visible="false" OnClick="Button1_Click"/>
```

And here is the error I get:

> Microsoft JScript runtime error: Unable to get value of the property 'click': object is null or undefined

Does anyone have any ideas as to what the problem might be? I've been tearing my hair out trying to work it out.

Comment: Why do you need to click two buttons on the client-side?  Why not just run the relevant code on the server-side?  Is the form posting to a 3rd-party location and you're trying to execute some code on your server as well?

Comment: If you can tell me a way to have input's onclick go to a c# method then I would be grateful (it can never seem to find the method when I try) - otherwise this was the only way I could think to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't you just do it with a single button?

```
<asp:Button id="Button1" runat="server" Text="Search" OnClick="Button1_Click"/>
```

Server-side code:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    // processing code here
}
```

Comment: I'm using a textbox and input to filter my GridView, so I need it to happen on input's onclick. The button was my way around getting the c# method to be called.

Comment: Does it *have* to be an `input` tag?  What's wrong with `asp:Button`?  It will essentially do the exact same thing.

Answer (score 1):

if you are not limited to java-script you can try using the trigger from jquery like this

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
            function check_user() {
           $("#<%=Button1.ClientID%>").trigger('click');
         //or

 $("#<%=Button1.ClientID%>").click();

            }  
</script>
```

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't seem to recognise jquery. Is it simple to setup?

Comment: Yes, simply include it. It's even available from Microsoft's CDN.

Comment: Sweet - it didn't break, but it didn't end up calling the button's OnClick method either...

Answer (score 0):

As you made the button invisible, asp.net is not rendering the button control in html. (You can check the HTML source). You can create a style and apply it to the asp.net button once it is rendered at client side to make it invisible.

```
.MyHiddenButtonStyle{display:none;}// add this in the header in styles

<input id="Submit1" type="button" name="search" value="Search" onclick="javascript:check_user()" />
<asp:Button id="Button1" runat="server" CssClass="MyHiddenButtonStyle" OnClick="Button1_Click"/>

function check_user() {
        document.getElementById('<%=Button1.ClientID%>').click();
    }
```

One more thing I have made the submit button as normal button. anyways you are raising a postback event using javascript.